# On Click toggling tooltip on generated label element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML that is generated dynamically:

```
<label class="passiveText smallText" title="Name: Smith, John , Occupation Code: BA81, Occupation 
Description: BUSINESS SYSTEMS M" rel="tooltip" style="margin-top:10px; width:80%; text-decoration:underline; 
color:#009245;" containeridx="0" id="lblBadge_7022_0">7022</label>
```

Now I have a jQuery function that when clicked makes a tooltip appear:

```
$( function()
{
    var targets = $( '[rel~=tooltip]' ),
        target  = false,
        tooltip = false,
        title   = false;
    targets.bind( 'click', function()
    {
    target  = $( this );
    tip = target.attr('title');
    tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );

    if( !tip || tip == '' )
        return false;

    tooltip.css( 'opacity', 0 )
           .html( tip )
           .appendTo( 'body' );

    var init_tooltip = function()
    {
        if( $( window ).width() < tooltip.outerWidth() * 1.5 )
            tooltip.css( 'max-width', $( window ).width() / 2 );
        else
            tooltip.css( 'max-width', 340 );

        var pos_left = target.offset().left + ( target.outerWidth() / 2 ) - ( tooltip.outerWidth() / 2 ),
            pos_top  = target.offset().top - tooltip.outerHeight() - 20;

        if( pos_left < 0 )
        {
            pos_left = target.offset().left + target.outerWidth() / 2 - 20;
            tooltip.addClass( 'left' );
        }
        else
            tooltip.removeClass( 'left' );

        if( pos_left + tooltip.outerWidth() > $( window ).width() )
        {
            pos_left = target.offset().left - tooltip.outerWidth() + target.outerWidth() / 2 + 20;
            tooltip.addClass( 'right' );
        }
        else
            tooltip.removeClass( 'right' );

        if( pos_top < 0 )
        {
            var pos_top  = target.offset().top + target.outerHeight();
            tooltip.addClass( 'top' );
        }
        else
            tooltip.removeClass( 'top' );

        tooltip.css( { left: pos_left, top: pos_top } )
               .animate({ top: '+=10', opacity: 1 }, 50);
    };

    init_tooltip();
    $( window ).resize( init_tooltip );

    var remove_tooltip = function()
    {
        tooltip.animate( { top: '-=10', opacity: 0 }, 50, function()
        {
            $( this ).remove();
        });

        target.attr( 'title', tip );
    };

    //target.bind( 'mouseleave', remove_tooltip );
    tooltip.bind( 'click', remove_tooltip );
});
```

});

What it is not doing is toggling like I want to. What I want is when the tooltip is up, and it's clicked again I want the tooltip to go away.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might want to use `.on()` which delegates the click handling on the parent to the selector. In this way you don't need to unbind since items added later, will be delegated as well.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: It looks like your code works as it is: http://jsfiddle.net/HSpyC/ What doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Thanks for making the fiddle Brent. What is not working is that when clicked the tooltip happens, however when clicked again it does not go away.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution I figured out:

```
$(function () {
    var targets = $('[rel~=tooltip]');

    targets.on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tooltip = $this.children('#tooltip');

        if (tooltip.length > 0) {
            tooltip.remove();

            return true;
        }

        tooltip = $('<div id="tooltip">');
        tooltip.text($this.attr('title'));

        var init_tooltip = function () {
            if ($(window).width() < tooltip.outerWidth() * 1.5)
                tooltip.css('max-width', $(window).width() / 2);
            else
                tooltip.css('max-width', 340);

            var pos_left = $this.offset().left + ($this.outerWidth() / 2) - (tooltip.outerWidth() / 2),
                            pos_top = $this.offset().top - tooltip.outerHeight() - 20;

            if (pos_left < 0) {
                pos_left = $this.offset().left + $this.outerWidth() / 2 - 20;
                tooltip.addClass('left');
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass('left');

            if (pos_left + tooltip.outerWidth() > $(window).width()) {
                pos_left = $this.offset().left - tooltip.outerWidth() + $this.outerWidth() / 2 + 20;
                tooltip.addClass('right');
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass('right');

            if (pos_top < 0) {
                var pos_top = $this.offset().top + $this.outerHeight();
                tooltip.addClass('top');
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass('top');

            tooltip.css({ left: pos_left, top: pos_top })
                   .animate({ top: '+=10', opacity: 1 }, 50);
        }
        init_tooltip();
        $(window).resize(init_tooltip);

        $this.append(tooltip);
    });
});
```